# What is the best way in Python to check if a string is the name of a city or the name of a country (also historical)

Tags: python, nlp, geotagging

I have a long list of strings containing names of cities or countries. The list also contain some names of countries that does not exist anymore like Prussia or the Ottman Empire.

```
l= [
'Russia',
'Smolensk',
'Moscow',
'Moscow',
'France',
'France',
'Russia',
'Prussia',
'Austria',
'Sweden',
'Constantinople',
'Russia',
'Great Britain',
'Spain',
'Portugal',
'Germany',
'Frankfurt',
'France',
'Leningrad',
'Paris',
'DDR',
'Paris',
'France',
'Paris',
'the United States',
'St. Helena',
]
```

I want to split that list into two `l_countries` and `l_cities`. One containing the cities names, and another containing country names.

I think the difficulty is to detect old-city and old-country names?

Like:

- Prussia (does not exist anymore)
- The DDR (does not exist anymore)
- Yugoslavia (does not exist anymore)
- Constantinople (now Istanbul)
- Leningrad (now Saint Petersburg)

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/176365/seeking-api-for-countries-states-cities-and-airports; https://restcountries.eu/

Comment: Thank you, but there is nothing on dealing with historic names on that thread... The difficulty here is to find old countries and old city names.